# Show a $W$ is a subspace and find its dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-verification

Let $W=\{(a,b,c)\}\in \mathbb{R}^{3} : b=a+c \}$. Show that $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and find $\dim(W)$.

My solution is :

Let $u=(a_1,b_1,c_1)$ and $v=(a_2,b_2,c_2)$ $\in W$

Then $a_1+c_1-b_1=0$ and $a_2+c_2-b_2=0$

The summation of this is zero and $ku$ is also zero , so $W$ is closed under multiplication and additional.

**Is my answer correct?** *If not, what is the correct answer?*

Comment: You should be a bit more explicit than the summation is zero and $k\mathbf u$ is zero so it's closed under the vector space operations.  But yes, that's how you do it.  Then you need to find the dimension of that subspace.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: No , could you help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, though you should write more steps.  For example, once you know $a_{1} + c_{1} - b_{1} = 0$ and $a_{2} + c_{2} - b_{2} = 0$, you should say:

Adding these two equations together gives:

$a_{1} + c_{1} - b_{1} + a_{2} + c_{2} - b_{2} = 0 + 0$, so:

$a_1 + a_2 + c_1 + c_2 - (b_1 + b_2) = 0$, but this means the vector $(a_1 + a_2, b_1 + b_2, c_1 + c_2)$ is in $W$, which means $W$ is closed under addition.

Similarly, you should write the details out for $ku$:

Since $a_1 + c_1 - b_1 = 0$, then for any scalar $k$, $ka_1 + kc_1 - kb_1 = k0 = 0$, which shows $(ka_1, kb_1, kc_1)$ is in $W$ for every scalar $k$.

Finally, you need to write down the dimension of $W$.  A good way to do this is to ask yourself: What does a vector in $W$ look like?  Well, if our vector is $(a,b,c)$, then $b = a + c$, so our vector is actually $(a, a + c, c)$.  But that means $a$ and $c$ can be anything, since there are no other conditions.  Now write this general vector as a sum of vectors where one has only $a$ present and one has only $c$ present:

$(a, a + c, c) = (a, a, 0) + (0, c , c) = a(1, 1, 0) + c(0,1,1)$.  So since $a$ and $c$ are free (i.e., they can be anything), that means $W$ is spanned by the vectors $(1,1,0)$ and $(0,1,1)$.  All that is left to do is show these vectors are linearly independent.  Do you know how to do this?  They *are*, and there are two of them, so that means dim $W = 2$.